# How can I tell proxy server not to cache the response?

Tags: java, caching, proxy, http-headers, httprequest

I found this to achieve this job:

> Cache-Control: private The next higher directive is “cache-control:
>   private”. It instructs proxies in the path not to cache the page. But
>   it permits browsers to cache the page. Proxies are shared resources
>   used by multiple users, and this directive tells them not to cache the
>   response. Browsers, as we have already noted, may still cache the
>   page.

But how can I add this to request header? These cache issues are relevant with response header. So what should I do to add this parameter to request header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using *Servlets*, then you can add / set the required **response** (not request) HTTP header.

Simple example.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
        // some code here

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private");

        // some code here
    }
}
```

Or you may use `response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private")`.

It's just that when using `setHeader()`, then if the header had already been set, the new value overwrites the previous one.

See Java EE API here:
[void addHeader(String name, String value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
[void setHeader(String name, String value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)